# Says my DDL statement contains syntax errors

Tags: mysql-workbench

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOrderDetails 
    @CustomerID AS INT
AS 
    SELECT OrderID, Quantity, TotalCost
    FROM orders
    WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID;
```

I know it's probably something simple but I don't see it. I'm sure it's a syntax error but I could not find a similar question to learn from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are no syntax errors, you might want to add the AS keyword before the BEGIN statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetOrderDetails 
    @CustomerID AS INT
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT OrderID, Quantity, TotalCost
    FROM orders
    WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID;
END;
```